# Zero file system space after gparted shrink

Tags: filesystem, gparted

I used gparted shrink to create some unallocated space from bootable ubuntu usb.
Now I get no file space left message and most programs have stopped working. But gparted still shows 20 gb free space in the partition that I shrank. df command shows 'used' less than '1k-blocks' but still 100% in use.
Please help. 
Here is output of df command from live usb. The last line is for the dirty partition-

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1940364         0   1940364   0% /dev
tmpfs             391192      6304    384888   2% /run
/dev/sdb         1517760   1517760         0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0       1462784   1462784         0 100% /rofs
aufs             1955944     48880   1907064   3% /
tmpfs            1955944     22420   1933524   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1955944         0   1955944   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1955944       132   1955812   1% /tmp
tmpfs             391192        96    391096   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sda3      443331760 422593388         0 100% /media/.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Some filesystems (notably the `ext*` family) don't let a regular user (that is, not root) fill up a disc. This is to let root get in and sort things after users are locked out because of the lack of disc space (amongst other scary scenarios). In any case, those scenarios probably don't apply to a USB key :-)

Fortunately, it's a tunable! Unmount the USB partition, and then run `tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda3`, and mount it again.

Comment: /dev/sda3 is not usb key. Its a primary partition on hard drive which is mounted on /  (root) and contains my ubuntu installation. It is showing as mounted in /media/...  because I ran df after running ubuntu from live usb.

Comment: @technoholick whoops, I messed up my edit above then. Could you fix it? Paste the output of `df <the USB key device>`. Once you tell me the device name I'll edit my answer to match.